# ValueProxy[int] throws error: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, types, python-multiprocessing, type-hinting

I have the following piece of code:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import ValueProxy

def test(value: ValueProxy[int]):
    print("foo")

test(None)
```

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 4, in <module>
    def test(value: ValueProxy[int]):
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I type-hint to `ValueProxy[int]`?

Answer (score 1):

Type hinting generics (= writing `ValueProxy[int]` instead of just `ValueProxy`) was added for the `multiprocessing.managers` module, along with other standard library modules, in Python 3.9 ([PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)).

See:

- [multiprocessing/managers.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0361556537686f857f1025ead75e6af4ca7cc94a#diff-9e59d8c837ebf181d34af715ac88bb8a4b6141ec18b703cef2c3c8136391abf7) (`__class_getitem__ = classmethod(types.GenericAlias)` was added)
- [Pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19423)
- [Issue on the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue39481)

You appear to be using a Python version older than 3.9.